# Lagrange multiplier for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

I am dealing with fluid-structure interaction problem and I have a pde subjected to a constraint .

I must use Lagrange multipliers but I don’t know how. Please, any one give a simple example for how to apply Lagrange multiplier to pde. So I can deal with my problem.

$\Omega $ is the fluid region and $B(t)$ is region occupied by a particle.$u$ is the velocity of the fluid ,$F$ is the external force and $\rho$ is the fluid density constant.p is the pressure and $\mu$ is the viscosity of the fluid
$$\rho (\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (u \cdot \nabla ))= F + \nabla \cdot \sigma \qquad \text{in} \quad \Omega \backslash B(t)$$
$$\nabla \cdot u=0 \qquad \text{in} \quad \Omega $$ 
$$\nabla \cdot \sigma = \frac{1}{2} \mu \nabla \cdot(\nabla u+\nabla u^t) -\nabla p$$

We also have the constraint defined in $B(t)$ $$u(x,t)= V(t)+w(t) \times (x-G(t))$$
Where $V$ is the translation velocity of the particle, $G$ is its center of mass and $w$ is the angular velocity.

Note that I am dealing with fictitious domain so we will integrate over the entire domain $\Omega$ in $\textbf{2 dimensions}$

$$u(x,0)=u_0 \qquad \text{in} \quad \Omega \backslash B(t) $$  and $u=0 $ on the boundary

Comment: Can you give us more details? e.g. the equation/constraint?

Comment: @caverac yes,I have edited

Comment: How about the initial/final condition and boundary conditions?

Comment: @Jan I have added them

Comment: @Jan I know that in order to find the variational formulation, we are going to multiply by by v in (H^1_0)^2 and integrate , but my problem is in the way we use Lagrange multiplier

Comment: You said you must use Lagrange multipliers, but what is your goal here? Writing down the variational formulation for the problem ?

Comment: @CheeHan yes I want to write the variational formulation

Comment: Your stress tensor seem to be missing a factor of $1/2$, assuming $\mu$ is the viscosity. Is your problem in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Where is the fictitious domain? Are you solving in $\Omega(t)$ or $\Omega(t)\setminus B(t)$? Is $u(0) = u_0$ the initial condition? If so, change it to $u(x,0) = u_0$.

Comment: @CheeHan ok I will edit, I am working in R^2 (2D) , and the fictitious domain is the whole domain Omega

Comment: @CheeHan  I know how to deal with the entire domain Omega by supposing that the particle is filled with the fluid... my problem exactly is in how to use Lagrange multiplier to write the weak form, l will be thankful if you help me manage this

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by "the particle is filled with the fluid". Nonetheless, in analogy to finding the Lagrange multiplier in Calculus, you proceed on how you would usually write the variational formulation, but now adding one term $\lambda\int_{B(t)} u(x,t) - \left(V(t) + w(t)\times (x-G(t))\right)\, dx$, where $\lambda$ is the (unknown) Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: @CheeHan why should the integral for the added term be over B(t)?

Comment: @CheeHan umm ok, I got it,thank you

Comment: That is because the constraint is defined only in $B(t)$. This is usually how one removes equality constraint using Lagrange multiplier. One warning would be that it is slightly different if you have integral constraint.

Comment: @CheeHan and what should I do if I have integral constraint? Also as I know that in this problem I have 2 constraints ,the second in  $\nabla\cdot u=0$ , why we removed that equality instead of this

Comment: It would be a double integral instead then, first is due to the integral constraint and you integrate again because of the variational formulation. I would imagine that you enforce that in your choice of function space, i.e. you look for functions that is divergence free; otherwise you will need to introduce another Lagrange multiplier for that. Actually, people in the field always say that pressure is the Lagrange multiplier enforcing the incompressibility condition [see here https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7474/pressure-as-a-lagrange-multiplier], but I can't really comment much.